# How do I resolve Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Fiscal Year')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post

I am accessing the data retrieved using an API and I am displaying it like this.

```
<Grid ><Typography variant="body1">Fiscal Year </Typography></Grid>
<TableContainer style={{width:600,height:170}}> 
{stats?<Table 
sx={{alignItems: "center",
display:""}}
>
{stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']?<TableBody>
                             <TableRow hover>
                                 <TableCell align="left"> Fiscal Year Ends</TableCell>
                                 <TableCell align="right">  {stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Fiscal Year Ends']===null?"N/A":stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Fiscal Year Ends']}</TableCell>
                             </TableRow>
                             <TableRow hover>
                                 <TableCell align="left"> Most Recent Quarter (mrq)</TableCell>
                                 <TableCell align="right">{stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Most Recent Quarter (mrq)']===null?"N/A":stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Most Recent Quarter (mrq)']}</TableCell>
                             </TableRow>
</TableBody>:"Loading"}
</Table> :<div>Loading...</div>}                        
</TableContainer>
```

But I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Fiscal Year')" despite proper data existing.
On doing console.log I can see this.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I could be wrong but maybe it doesn't have time to load? Maybe try `{stats && stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I believe by the time compiler enters **stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']**, your API is still busy fetching the response.
I would suggest you add a nullable operator like this

`stats?.['Financial Highlights']?.['Fiscal Year']`

It will pass this check and render the accurate result once the HTTP call get some data to show.

Comment: It worked. It was just taking a while to fetch the response. Thanks a lot.